# Probability of pairs

Tags: probability

Suppose $N$ people each generate a random number $[1,\cdots,N]$. On average, how many pairs will there be, given that a pair means that person $i$ generated $j$ and person $j$ generated $i$?

Comment: Interesting question. I assume it does not count as a pair if a person generates their "own" number?

Comment: The possible number of pairs is of course at most $\lfloor N/2 \rfloor$ and in principle grows much slower. (I also assume that everyone generates their number independently, and with a uniform distribution over $1, \dots, N$.) And a little simulation suggests that as $N$ becomes large, the expectation converges from below to $0.5$.

Comment: If you require $i \not =j$ then there are $\frac12N(N-1)$ potential such pairs and each one has probability $\frac1{N^2}$ of occurring then the expected number is $\frac{N-1}{2N} = \frac12 - \frac{1}{2N}$.  (In addition the expected number of cases of people choosing their own number is $1$).

Comment: @Henry: want to post this as an answer? Maybe elaborate that the number of pairs is binomial with parameters $\frac{1}{N^2}$ and $\frac{1}{2}N(N-1)$, for the expectation you give.

Comment: @StephanKolassa I am not sure it is binomial - they are not independent and, as you commented, the maximum is $\lfloor N/2\rfloor$

Comment: This seems connected to the famous [Birthday Problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

*From comments:*

If you require $i \not =j$ then there are $\frac12N(N-1)$ potential such pairs and each one has probability $\frac1{N^2}$ of occurring then, by linearity of expectation, the expected number is $\frac{N-1}{2N} = \frac12 - \frac{1}{2N}$.

(In addition the expected number of cases of people choosing their own number is $1$).

This does not have a binomial distribution: the pairs are not independent and (as
Stephan Kolassa commented) the maximum number of pairs is $\lfloor N/2\rfloor$.

Comment: I'm getting doubts about this... where does the probability $\frac{1}{N^2}$ come from?

Comment: ... but simulating $N=3, 5, 10$ with 1e6 simulations each yields pretty much the expectation you get. Have an upvote, and I would still be interested in where that probability comes from.

Comment: @StephanKolassa  Player $i$ gets number $j$ with probability $\frac1N$ and independently player $j$ gets number $i$ with probability $\frac1N$, so for given $i$ and $j$ distinct, the probability they get each other's number is the product $\frac1{N^2}$.  Then $\frac1{N^2} \times \frac12N(N-1)= \frac{N-1}{2N}$

Comment: ... but how does this square with the fact that if $(i,j)$ are a pair, then we *know* that $(i,k)$ and $(k,j)$ *cannot* be a pair for $k\neq i,j$?

Comment: It doesn't matter. The quantity we are looking for is the expectation of a sum (of indicator functions), which is always equal to the sum of the expectations.

Comment: @StephanKolassa That is the power of linearity of expectation.  You know that the number of cases of a particularly pair appearing is $0$ or $1$ and the expected number of that particularly pair appearing is $\frac1{N^2}$ so the total expected number of pairs is that expectation of a particular pair multiplied by the number of pairs to consider.

Answer (score 7):

Different approach to get the same answer:

For a person to be part of a pair, they need to choose a number other than their own (which has probability $\frac{N-1}{N}$), and the person/number they chose needs to complete the pair (which has probability $\frac{1}{N}$). The probability a person is part of a pair is, thus, $\frac{N-1}{N^2}$.

By the linearity of expectation, the expected number of people who are part of a pair is $\frac{N-1}{N}$, so the expected number of pairs is $\frac{N-1}{2N}$.

Comment: That's why I divide the final answer by 2.

Comment: The number of pairs is equal to half the number of people who are part of a pair.